# My array has comping errors and I am unsure on how to fix it

Tags: java, sum

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to input a length creating a randomized array of that length full of doubles. Then to compute the average, the portion of my program which doesn't work is my for loop where I tried to calculate the sum.

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Arrays;
public class Average {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum=0;
System.out.println("Enter a number");
//create an array with the size entered by the user
double[] array = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
//populate the array with doubles
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    array[i] = rand.nextDouble();

}
for (int b=0;b<array; b++) {
sum+=array[b];  

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
}
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: because it doesn't compile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have a look at this for writing better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If it doesn't compile, you would get an error message describing the problem.

Comment: 1 error found:
File: /Users/ashtonmeade/Downloads/Average.java  [line: 19]
Error: /Users/ashtonmeade/Downloads/Average.java:19: operator < cannot be applied to int,double[]

Comment: its on the line with my for loop

Comment: You are comparing an array with an int. You need to get the size of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: You already did it right in your first loop: `for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
for (int b=0;b<array; b++)
```

To this:

```
for (int b=0;b<array.length; b++)
```